# runtime error 91 object variable or with block variable not set database

Tags: excel, vba

I have a database where all the data are in majuscule and I'm trying to keep only the first letter like that, my code is

```
Sub nompropio()

Dim rng As Range
Dim cell As Range

Set rng = Range("A1:T17058")

For Each cell In rng
Next cell

If Not cell.HasFormula Then   >>>here is the eror
End If

cell.Value = WorksheetFunction.Proper(cell.Value)

End Sub
```

I don't know if having blank cells is a problem or if some columns are only numbers but none of those cells have formula i just put it because the example was like that and I tried to work it without that part but neither it worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should work with this syntax:

```
Sub nompropio()

Dim rng As Range
Dim cell As Range

Set rng = Range("A1:T17058")

For Each cell In rng
    If Not cell.HasFormula Then cell.Value = WorksheetFunction.Proper(cell.Value)
Next
End Sub
```

**updated post**

The version below uses variant arrays and `SpecialCells` to run the same process much faster than the range loop version above.

```
Sub Recut()
Dim X
Dim rng1 As Range
Dim rng2 As Range
Dim lngRow As Long
Dim lngCol As Long


On Error Resume Next
Set rng1 = Range("A1:T17058").SpecialCells(xlConstants)
On Error GoTo 0

If rng1 Is Nothing Then Exit Sub

For Each rng2 In rng1.Areas
    If rng2.Cells.Count > 1 Then
    X = rng2.Value2

    For lngRow = 1 To UBound(X, 1)
        For lngCol = 1 To UBound(X, 2)
            X(lngRow, lngCol) = WorksheetFunction.Proper(X(lngRow, lngCol))
        Next
    Next
    rng2.Value2 = X
    Else
    rng2.Value = WorksheetFunction.Proper(rng2.Value)
    End If
Next

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

The error you're indicating comes because the variable is out of scope. In fact,

1. In your loop, you define the variable implicitly:

   ```
   For Each cell In rng
   Next cell
   ```
2. Out of the Each loop, you try to call the variable:

   ```
   If Not cell.HasFormula Then   '>>>here is the error, because "cell" it's something within the previous loop, but it's nothing here so the compiler tells you "hey, I'm sorry, but I didn't set your variable".
   End If
   ```

Clearly, the variable is out-of-scope because it is defined in the `For Each` loop so it exists only within the scope of the loop. If you want to perform something on each cell without formulas, then this is the right way to go:

```
For Each cell In rng '<-- for each cell...
    If Not cell.HasFormula Then   '<-- perform if the cell has no formula
        cell.Value = WorksheetFunction.Proper(cell.Value) '<--action to perform
    End If '<-- end the if-then statement
Next cell '<-- go to the next cell of the range
```